# How to access An element ID with a string

Tags: javascript, html, spring-mvc

I have my requirement which is useless and loss of your time here:-
So, if I have

```
<form:amount id= "stackOverflowAMT" path ="stackOverflowAMT" size="10" maxlength="11"/>
```

And if I create a String in Java script, say `stringX ="stackOverflowAMT"`
is it possible to use this string as ID of stackOverflowAMT.

I tried a lot , now just want to assure whether it is possible or not 
Could Your help .Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access it using:

```
document.getElementById(stringX)
```

Or in jQuery:

```
$('#' + stringX)
```

Hope that helps.